# Similar tags: to use synonyms or just merge?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, guidelines

Consider for example, these two tags: [ultragrid](/questions/tagged/ultragrid) and [ultrawingrid](/questions/tagged/ultrawingrid).

- One has 67 questions, the other 48.
- The first is a shorter, more popular name. It is the name of the class. The latter is the official product name by Infragistics. It is namespace the class resides in.

What are some guidelines for deciding whether or not these two tags should become synonyms or simply merged? Here are some considerations:

- Keeping both to ease finding tags for users
- Merging if the total number of questions is very low

Are there any other guidelines that would come into play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can think of any reason why the synonym could be broken, they should be synonymized, not merged. If you synonymize without merging, both tags still exist but are shown as the same tag, so at any time you can break the synonym and both will show up as whichever tag was entered by the user.

Comment: By synonym being 'broken', you mean separating it out as its own tag again in the future?

Comment: @JeffBridgman yeah, "breaking" the two back into their separate tags. I had to do it once due to an incorrect synonym

Answer (score 2):

Merging and adding synonym is not exclusive. If both tag can be reasonably useful, all questions should be merged to "official", where all the rest of tags become its synonyms.